# Why don't exceptions in spring-data-commons extend DataAccessException?

Tags: spring-data

I'm trying to handle the Spring DAO Exceptions (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#dao-exceptions) in the service layer of my application, just to discover that the exceptions in the spring-data-commons module don't extend *org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException.DataAccessException*.

Example: [PropertyReferenceException](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mapping/PropertyReferenceException.html).

As far as I can tell, all exceptions in this module, and maybe in the other sub-modules of Spring Data projects should extend *DataAccessException*.

Is there anything obvious that I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for Spring Data to use Spring Core's DataAccessException hierarchy as one may use the PersistenceExceptionTranslator. The latter translates thrown exceptions of e.g. Spring Data Repositories to a DataAccessException subtype.

PersistenceExceptionTranslator kicks in automatically when marking your repository with the "@Repository" annotation. The service (using the annotated repository) may catch the DataAccessException, if needed.

Comment: A [PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-exception-translation) has to be registered in order to activate Exception translation for `@Repository` annotated interfaces.